# How to set the UIView become first Responder?

Tags: ios, uiresponder

I am learning `UIResponder` now. I wrote some test code. In my code I want to let the `UIView` become the first responder, but I failed. My test steps are:

1. Create a `UIView` in a storyboard.
2. Created a class that extends `UIView` for this view, and override the methods `canBecomeFirstResponder:` and `becomeFirstResponder` to return `YES`.
3. In the method of the view controller's `viewDidAppear:` method, test it:

   ```
   - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [self.viewD becomeFirstResponder];
       NSLog(@"%d ", [self.viewD isFirstResponder]);
   }
   ```

The result of `isFirstResponder` is always `NO`.

I have no idea why. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron Brager  thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> becomeFirstResponder Notifies the receiver that it is about to become first responder in its window.
>   YES if the receiver accepts first-responder status or NO if it refuses this status. The default implementation returns YES, accepting first responder status.
>
> A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder) and the new responder can become first responder.

In your case your view refuses the status that's why its NO every time.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Why the view refuses it? because the current responder can not  resign first-responder status? 
-->" [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];" can resign first responder,I did it.
Because the value of userinteractionEnabled is NO? 
--> after check it, the value is YES

Comment: Does that fix your problem?

Comment: all the views are created through storyboard. I think yes.

Comment: No, the result of isFirstResponder is also NO.

Answer (score 0):

so in your overrides make sure your calling super

also
you can try to make sure that view is in front and visible 
you can try to end editing of the current parent view
before calling becomeFirstResponder

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.D];
  [self.view endEditing:true];
  [self.D becomeFirstResponder];
```

also any reason your not calling super in your ViewDidAppear?

Comment: hi David Yang Liu.I did it,but... also NO.
 I also call  [super viewDidAppear:animated] at the first line in the method.

Comment: after deleted the code in my implementation file of view,it works!
`//-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
//{
//    return YES;
//}`